# Add an attribute to a sibling of element when the child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `table` with several columns, which looks like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
        <button id="1" class="btn btn-info btn-sm _edit_btn">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Asht</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Sughd</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3505207000000</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is to add an attribute to each `<td>` element on the button click of the button which is located on the very first `<td>` of the table.

I use jQuery for this purpose. I tried to do it using the siblings function but it doesn't work as the `<td>` elements are not siblings of the `<button>` element but of the other `<td>` elements.

Comment: "*[It] doesn't work as the `<td>` elements are not siblings of the `<button>` element but of the other `<td>` elements.*" - then in order to use the `siblings()` method you simply need to navigate from the `<button>` to the element of which the `<td>` elements are siblings of.

Comment: you want to add the attribute to every td which isn't the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use `closest()` to find the parent `tr` of the `button`, then `find()` to get the `td`, like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').attr('foo', 'bar');
});
```

If you'd prefer to use `siblings()` as you mentioned, then you can get the parent `td` and use `siblings()` on that:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').siblings().attr('foo', 'bar');
});
```

Note that this version will not add the attribute to the first `td` element, if that was your intention.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse to closest tr element using `.closest()` method and then find `td` in it:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').attr('someattr','attrval');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one for two cases:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    //if you want to add attribute to all tds then use this line
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td").attr("your-attribute", "value");

    //if you want to add attribute to all tds except the first one then use this line
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(.sorting_1)").attr("your-attribute", "value");
});
```